# liferay-ui:journal-article works only first time after portlet deployment and then blank

Tags: liferay-6

(Note its for Liferay 6.1)
Struggling with the Liferay-ui for displaying a journal-article with the following tag:

```
<liferay-ui:journal-article articleResourcePrimKey="10656" />
```

As you can see i have hardcoded the articleResourcePrimKey for sample, and that article exists in the cms. Its WCM structured contents and template is also associated with it.

Everything works fine for the first refresh as after the portlet deployment on the server, but the next refresh for the same returns nothing (a blank page as if liferay-ui is not present at all)

I have changed the temaplte to Cacheable and then it works fine until i made modification to the template or content associated with it, but as soon i modify the template or content from WCM, it starts behaving the same.

When ever it worked just after redeployment and on first refresh of the page where the portlet is placed.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used groupId and articleId rather than articleResourcePrimKey, and it works fine. These two values are easily discoverable within the admin screens for web content.

Using Liferay 6.0, but about to upgrade to 6.1 and fully expecting it to work.